# Difference between #include<...> and #include"..."?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

What is the meaning of include "abc.h" and how it is different from include ?

Comment: here you go, do some searching next time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Including `"abc.h"` will look in the current directory. `<abc.h>` will look in the include directory, which can be provided at compile-time.

Comment: Including "abc.h" will look in the current directory and if it is not found there, it also checks include path directory.

Comment: Ah. Never knew that :).

Comment: I can't find a particular header file in current directory but it is in some other directory other than include , hence compiler is unable to open it . Can copying it to current directory may help ?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Copy it to the directory containing your other cpp/header files of the current project and include it using double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`<abc.h>` is usually for built-in use such as math while `"abc.h"` is usually for customized use.

Answer (score 0):

is being looked for in your header include path and "abc.h" relative to your source file's path first.